# Redirect to new page after form submiting, show content and than download file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm having trouble with redirecting to a new page after sending the form, displaying content and then download a constructed file.

Separately it's working fine I can redirect to page B after submitting the form, display content and `echo $_SESSION['success'] (some text)`, but there is no file downloaded.

On the other hand, if I block redirecting a new file is constructed and downloaded, but the form is not refreshed and echo `$_SESSION['success'] (some text)` seems not working. I need to send the form and after that back to the original page, or redirect to another (page B), display `echo $_SESSION['success']` and download zip file.

I've tried several things. First of all, I know that in PHP it's impossible to download the file and then redirect, that's why I tried redirect to page B and execute creating the file with: `if (isset($_SESSION["file"])) include ('fileGenerator.php');`

I tried this several ways using also JS "onload", but the thing is the same - download starts on the previous page, the form is filled with previous content and echo `$_SESSION['success']` is not working also. When I refresh the page it's showing a success message (I tried refreshing page too).

```
//It's my way of creating the zip file.

$files = array("./database/errorCodes/ReadMe.txt","./database/errorCodes/CMakeLists.txt","./database/errorCodes/".$_SESSION['file'].".cpp");
    $zipName = $_SESSION['file'].".zip";
    unset($_SESSION['file']);
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($zipName, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $zip->addFile($file);
    }
    $zip->close();
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipName);
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipName));
    readfile($zipName);
    header("Connection: close");
```

After several attempts, I have no idea what to do. If anybody has an idea what to do please let me know.

IN A NUT:
on page A (records.php) with form:

```
<form class=formAddNewRecord action="records.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I'm sending with buttom:

```
<div class=input-group><button type="submit" id="registerError" name="registerError" class="btn">Generate code</button></div>
```

than in server.php which is included at the beginig of records.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['registerError'])){
... comunicating with database, operations...
 if (<checking if sth exists in database>) {
                $_SESSION['success'] = "Error successfully added!";
                //creating file
                $_SESSION['file'] = <fileName>;
                //if (isset($_SESSION["file"])) include ('fileGenerator.php');
                $newDepartment = $newPart= $newAssembly= $phone= $email= $errorName= $chkEmail= $chkPhone= $chkSignal= $chkInfo= $chkCode= "";
                $instruction="Write your instruction here.";
                header('location: account.php');
            }
```

And than on page:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])): ?>
<div class=success style="width: 100%">
<h6 style="padding-top: 10px; text-align: center">
<?php
    echo $_SESSION['success'];
    unset($_SESSION['success']);
?>
</h6>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

WHOLE FILES server.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $name =$surname = $username = $email1 = $email2 = $password1= $password2= $department= $assebly= $part= $newDepartment = $newPart= $newAssembly= $phone= $email= $errorName= $chkEmail= $chkPhone= $chkSignal= $chkInfo= $chkCode=$date=$externalCodeField= "";
    $errors = array();
    $instruction="Write your instruction here.";
    $user_id=$emailUser='';
    //creating/opening database
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    class MyDB extends SQLite3
    {
        function __construct($filename)
        {
            $this->open($filename);
        }
    }
    $db = new MyDB('./database/cern.db');
     if(!$db) {
         array_push($errors,"ERROR 404 - Database not found!");
       }
    //--------------------------------------------------------
if (isset($_POST['registerError'])){
    $department = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST['department']);
    $newDepartment = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST['newDepartment']);
    $assembly = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST['assembly']);
    $newAssembly = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST['newAssembly']);
    $part = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST['part']);
    $newPart = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST['newPart']);
    $errorName = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST['errorName']);
    $chkEmail = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST['chkEmail']);
    $email = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST['email']);
    $chkPhone = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST['chkPhone']);
    $phone= SQLite3::escapeString($_POST['phone']);
    $chkSignal = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST['chkSignal']);
    $chkInfo = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST['chkInfo']);
    $instruction = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST['instruction']);
    $chkCode = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST['chkCode']);

    //Validate if error has been already taken
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM errors WHERE name=:errorName AND department=:departmentName AND assembly=:assemblyName AND part=:partName';
    $sth = $db->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindValue(':errorName', $errorName, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    if ($department=="new" && !empty($newDepartment))$sth->bindValue(':departmentName', $newDepartment, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    else if ($department!="new") $sth->bindValue(':departmentName', $department, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    if ($assembly=="new" && !empty($newAssembly))$sth->bindValue(':assemblyName', $newAssembly, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    else if ($assembly!="new") $sth->bindValue(':assemblyName', $assembly, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    if ($part=="new" && !empty($newPart))$sth->bindValue(':partName', $newPart, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    else if ($part!="new")  $sth->bindValue(':partName', $part, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $result = $sth->execute();
    if ($result->fetchArray())array_push($errors,"•This error already exists");

    //ensure that form fields are filled properly
    if ($department=="new" && empty($newDepartment))array_push($errors,"•New department name is required.");
    if ($assembly=="new" && empty($newAssembly))array_push($errors,"•New assembly name is required.");
    if ($part=="new" && empty($newPart))array_push($errors,"•New part name is required.");
    if (empty($errorName))array_push($errors,"•Error name is required.");
    if ($chkEmail=="Email" && empty($email))array_push($errors,"•Email is required.");
    if ($chkPhone=="Phone" && empty($phone))array_push($errors,"•Phone is required.");
    if ($chkPhone=="Phone" && !empty($phone) && !is_numeric($phone))array_push($errors,"•It is not a telephone number.");
    if (substr( $phone, 0, 1 ) != "+" && !empty($phone))array_push($errors,"•Telephone number has to start from +xx.");
    if ($chkInfo=="Information" && (empty($instruction) || $instruction=="Write your instruction here."))array_push($errors,"•Instruction is required.");
    if ($chkCode=="Code" && isset ($_FILES ['code'])){
        //checking if file was added
        if ($_FILES ["code"] ["error"] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) array_push($errors,"•File was not uploaded. .cpp file is required.");
        else{
            //checking if it's proper extension
            if($_FILES['code']['type'] != 'text/plain') array_push($errors,"•Improper extension. .cpp extension is required.");
        }
    }
    //if there are no errors save user to database
    if (count($errors)==0){
        $date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        //adding which user added error
        $username=$_SESSION["username"];
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=:login';
        $sth = $db->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindValue(':login', $username, SQLITE3_TEXT);
        $result = $sth->execute();
        if($row = $result->fetchArray()) {
            $user_id = $row['user_id'];
            $name= $row['name'];
            $surname = $row['surname'];
            $emailUser = $row['email'];
        }
        else array_push($errors,"•Critical error! Please contact help immediately!");

        $tmpDepartment=$tmpAssembly=$tmpPart='';
        $options=' ';
        if ($department=="new" && !empty($newDepartment))$tmpDepartment=$newDepartment;
        else if ($department!="new") $tmpDepartment=$department;
        if ($assembly=="new" && !empty($newAssembly))$tmpAssembly=$newAssembly;
        else if ($assembly!="new") $tmpAssembly=$assembly;
        if ($part=="new" && !empty($newPart))$tmpPart=$newPart;
        else if ($part!="new") $tmpPart=$part;

        if ($chkEmail!="Email")$email='';
        if ($chkPhone!="Phone")$phone='';
        if ($chkInfo!="Information")$instruction='';

        if ($chkEmail=="Email")$options=$options.'✉';
        if ($chkPhone=="Phone")$options=$options.'☎';
        if ($chkSignal=="Signal")$options=$options.'☠';
        if ($chkInfo=="Information")$options=$options.'☑';
        if($chkCode=="Code") {
            $options=$options.'✎';
            $_SESSION['externalCode'] = "text";
        }
        $db->exec("INSERT INTO errors (user_id, name, department, assembly, part, date, options, email, phone, instruction) VALUES ('$user_id','$errorName','$tmpDepartment','$tmpAssembly','$tmpPart','$date','$options','$email','$phone','$instruction')");
        $res = $db->query("SELECT * FROM errors WHERE department='$tmpDepartment' AND assembly='$tmpAssembly' AND part='$tmpPart' AND name='$errorName'");
        if ($row = $res->fetchArray()) {
            $error_id=md5($row['error_id']);
            $db->exec("UPDATE errors SET error_id_md='$error_id' WHERE department='$tmpDepartment' AND assembly='$tmpAssembly' AND part='$tmpPart' AND name='$errorName'");
            $_SESSION['success'] = "Error successfully added!";
            //creating file
            $_SESSION['file'] = strval($row['error_id']);
            //if (isset($_SESSION["file"])) include ('fileGenerator.php');
            $newDepartment = $newPart= $newAssembly= $phone= $email= $errorName= $chkEmail= $chkPhone= $chkSignal= $chkInfo= $chkCode= "";
            $instruction="Write your instruction here.";
            //header('location: account.php');
        }
        else {
            array_push($errors,"•Critical error! Please contact help immediately!");
            $newDepartment = $newPart= $newAssembly= $phone= $email= $errorName= $chkEmail= $chkPhone= $chkSignal= $chkInfo= $chkCode= "";
            $instruction="Write your instruction here.";
        }
    }
} //register new error
```

records.php

```
<?php include ('server.php');
if (empty($_SESSION['username'])){
    header('location: login.php');
}
// logout home if there is no action after 600s
$inactive = 600;
if( !isset($_SESSION['timeout']) ) $_SESSION['timeout'] = time() + $inactive;
$session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
if($session_life > $inactive){
    session_destroy(); header("location:login.php");
}
$_SESSION['timeout']=time();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Error Handler</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<style> body {background: #ffffff url("./images/cern.jpg") no-repeat top;}</style>
<header class="flags">
    <a href="#"><img src="./images/german.jpg" class="iconFlags" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="./images/poland.jpg" class="iconFlags" alt=""></a>
    <a href="records.php"><img src="./images/english.jpg" class="iconFlags" alt=""></a>
</header>
<body>
<div class=container>
    <div class=row>
        <div class=col-md-12>
            <div class=headerHome>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar navbar-expand-lg">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="font-size: 15px;"><img src="./images/cern-logo.png" class="iconLogo" alt="">Error Handler|</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainmenu" aria-controls="mainmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Przełącznik nawigacji">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainmenu">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="home.php">About</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="records.php">Add new record</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="account.php">Profile info</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="home.php?logout='1'">Logout</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=row>
        <div class=col-md-12>
            <div class=content>
                <?php if (isset($_SESSION["username"])): ?>
                    <p style="font-size: 12px; margin-bottom: 0;">You are logged in as: <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong></p>
                    <form class=formAddNewRecord action="records.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class=row>
                            <div class=col-md-6>
                                <h5 style="color:#4CAF50;">ADD NEW ERROR</h5>
                                <?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])): ?>
                                    <div class=success style="width: 100%">
                                        <h6 style="padding-top: 10px; text-align: center">
                                            <?php
                                            echo $_SESSION['success'];
                                            unset($_SESSION['success']);
                                            ?>
                                        </h6>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif ?>
                                <?php include ('errors.php'); ?>
                                <?php
                                $php_array=array();
                                $res = $db->query('SELECT DISTINCT department,assembly FROM errors;');
                                while ($row = $res->fetchArray()) {
                                    array_push($php_array,$row['department']);
                                    array_push($php_array,$row['assembly']);
                                }
                                ?><!-- selecting only different pairs (department, assembly)-->
                                <?php
                                $php_array_2=array();
                                $res = $db->query('SELECT DISTINCT department,assembly,part FROM errors;');
                                while ($row = $res->fetchArray()) {
                                    array_push($php_array_2,$row['department']);
                                    array_push($php_array_2,$row['assembly']);
                                    array_push($php_array_2,$row['part']);
                                }
                                ?><!-- selecting only different pairs (assembly, part)-->
                                <div class=input-group>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        function populateAssembly(setOption,secondList){
                                            const s2 = document.getElementById(secondList);
                                            s2.innerHTML="";
                                            let optionArray =[];
                                            optionArray = <?php echo json_encode($php_array);?>;

                                            const addNewOption = document.createElement("option");
                                            addNewOption.value ='new';
                                            addNewOption.innerHTML = 'Add new';
                                            s2.options.add(addNewOption);

                                            if(Array.isArray(optionArray) && optionArray.length){ // array exists and is not empty
                                                for(let i = 0; i < optionArray.length; i++)
                                                {
                                                    if(optionArray[i]===setOption) {
                                                        const newOption = document.createElement("option");
                                                        newOption.value = optionArray[i+1];
                                                        newOption.innerHTML = optionArray[i+1];
                                                        s2.options.add(newOption);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        } <!-- DYNAMIC SELECT FOR ASSEMBLY-->
                                        function populatePart(setOption,secondList,firstList){
                                            const s2 = document.getElementById(secondList);
                                            s2.innerHTML="";

                                            let optionArray=[];
                                            optionArray = <?php echo json_encode($php_array_2);?>;

                                            const addNewOption = document.createElement("option");
                                            addNewOption.value ='new';
                                            addNewOption.innerHTML = 'Add new';
                                            s2.options.add(addNewOption);

                                            if(Array.isArray(optionArray) && optionArray.length){ // array exists and is not empty
                                                for(let i = 0; i < optionArray.length; i++)
                                                {
                                                    if(optionArray[i]===document.getElementById(setOption).value) {
                                                        if(optionArray[i-1]===document.getElementById(firstList).value){
                                                            const newOption = document.createElement("option");
                                                            newOption.value = optionArray[i+1];
                                                            newOption.innerHTML = optionArray[i+1];
                                                            s2.options.add(newOption);
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        } <!-- DYNAMIC SELECT FOR PART-->
                                    </script>
                                    <label for="department">Department:</label><select id="department" name="department" class="dep" required onclick="const elementID='dvNewDepartment'; const chosenValue='new'; ShowHideList(this,elementID,chosenValue)" onchange="populateAssembly(this.value,'assembly'); populatePart('assembly','part','department')">
                                        <option value="new" selected>Add new</option>
                                        <?php $res = $db->query('SELECT DISTINCT department FROM errors;');
                                        while ($row = $res->fetchArray()) {
                                            $tmp = $row['department'];
                                            echo "<option value='$tmp'>" . $tmp . "</option>";
                                        }
                                        ?> <!-- ADDING OPTIONS TO DEPARTMENT SELECT -->
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div id="dvNewDepartment" class=input-group style="display: block"><label for="newDepartment">New Department:</label><input name="newDepartment" id="newDepartment" value="<?php echo $newDepartment; ?>"></div>
                                <div class=input-group>
                                    <label for="assembly">Assembly:</label><select id="assembly" name="assembly" class="dep" required onclick="const elementID='dvNewAssembly'; const chosenValue='new'; ShowHideList(this,elementID,chosenValue)" onchange="populatePart('assembly','part','department')">
                                        <option value="new">Add new</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div id="dvNewAssembly" class=input-group style="display: block"><label for="newAssembly">New Assembly:</label><input name="newAssembly" id="newAssembly" value="<?php echo $newAssembly; ?>"></div>
                                <div class=input-group>
                                    <label for="part">Part:</label><select id="part" name="part" class="dep" required onclick="const elementID='dvNewPart'; const chosenValue='new'; ShowHideList(this,elementID,chosenValue)">
                                        <option value="new">Add new</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div id="dvNewPart" class=input-group style="display: block"><label for="newPart">New Part:</label><input name="newPart" id="newPart" value="<?php echo $newPart; ?>"></div>
                                <div class=input-group><label for="errorName">Title of error:</label><input type="text" id="errorName" name="errorName" required value="<?php echo $errorName; ?>"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class=col-md-6>
                                <label class=container2 for="chkEmail"> Inform via email about error occurrence.<input  type="checkbox" id="chkEmail" name="chkEmail" value="Email" onclick="const elementID='dvEmail';
                                ShowHideDiv(this,elementID)" <?php echo ($chkEmail=="Email" ? 'checked' : '');?>><span class=checkmark></span></label>
                                <div id="dvEmail" class=input-group style="display: none"><label for="email">Email:</label><input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"></div>
                                <label class=container2 for="chkPhone"> Inform via phone about error occurrence.<input type="checkbox" id="chkPhone" name="chkPhone" value="Phone" onclick="const elementID='dvPhone';
                                ShowHideDiv(this,elementID)" <?php echo ($chkPhone=="Phone" ? 'checked' : '');?>><span class=checkmark></span></label>
                                <div id="dvPhone" class=input-group style="display: none"><label for="phone">Phone number (+xx):</label><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>"></div>
                                <label class=container2 for="chkSignal">Mark as severe error.<input type="checkbox" id="chkSignal" name="chkSignal" value="Signal" onclick="const elementID='severeWarning';
                                ShowHideDiv(this,elementID)" <?php echo ($chkSignal=="Signal" ? 'checked' : '');?>><span class=checkmark></span></label>
                                <p id="severeWarning" class="warning" style="display:none;">Warning: Severe error alarm contains visual and signal medium!</p>
                                <label class=container2 for="chkInfo"> Add instruction what to do.<input  type="checkbox" id="chkInfo" name="chkInfo" value="Information" onclick="const elementID='dvInfo';
                                ShowHideDiv(this,elementID)" <?php echo ($chkInfo=="Information" ? 'checked' : '');?> onload="const elementID='dvInfo'; ShowHideDiv(this,elementID)"><span class=checkmark></span></label>
                                <div id="dvInfo" class=input-text style="display: none"><label for="instruction">Add instruction:</label><textarea id="instruction" name="instruction"><?php echo $instruction; ?></textarea></div><br>
                                <label class=container2 for="chkCode"> Execute C++ code in part after error emerging.<input  type="checkbox" id="chkCode" name="chkCode" value="Code" onclick="const elementID1='dvCode'; const elementID2='warningCode';
                                ShowHide2Div(this,elementID1, elementID2)"><span class=checkmark></span></label>
                                <div id="dvCode" class=button-wrap style="display: none"><label class =new-button for="code">Upload.cpp</label><input id="code" name="code" type="file"></div><br>
                                <p id="warningCode" class="warning" style="display:none; margin-top: -20px;">Warning: Be sure C++ code is compilable and has proper structure - main function has to look like this: void externalCode(){your own code}. Don't forget to add all includes. You can find more information in "About" or read ReadMe.txt</p>
                                <div class=input-group><button type="submit" id="registerError" name="registerError" class="btn">Generate code</button></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                <?php endif ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class=footer>
    © 2019 Kacper Raciborski All Rights Reserved
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="form.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code probably does not show us enough of what goes on when! But did you look in the PHP Error Log yet. Do you see a message like `Headers already sent`

Comment: _First of all, I know that in PHP it's impossible to download the file and then redirect_ That is an incorrect assumtion!  **You will have to show us ALL the code if you want help with this issue**

Comment: It is Impossible to redirect to another page if **Anything** even a null byte has been sent from the script **before** the `header('Location: some.php');` has been run. _So it is imperative for us to see all the code in this script so we can see the order in which you are doing things_

Comment: Ok but it's really really big, but I will try.

Comment: You can not return more than one resource in the same HTTP response. You need to output your “new page” first, and then trigger a second request for your download from there, on the _client side_. (F.e. via a meta refresh or via JavaScript.)

Comment: "This code probably does not show us enough of what goes on when! But did you look in the PHP Error Log yet. Do you see a message like Headers already sent – RiggsFolly" I'm looking now. I have't used it before. And I added part of the code. As I said it's a big project.

Comment: @RiggsFolley "Headers already sent" and it's pointing at this line '<div id="dvPhone" class=input-group style="display: none"><label for="phone">Phone number (+xx):</label><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>"></div>' . It's bizzare.